# How do I assign a variable to a column in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my example code

```
import pandas as pd
import nampy as np

data = pd.read_csv("waiterTip.csv", sep=";")

Print(data)
```

The "data" output is as follows:

```
    tipAmount    billAmount 
0            5            34
1           17           108
2           11            64
3            8            88
4           14            99
5            5            51
```

I want to create a "Y" variable from the column "tipAmount"

```
Y = ?
```

Comment: I have no idea what `Y = ?` means. `Y = df['tipAmount'].values.tolist()`?

Comment: do you mean `Y = data['tipAmount']`?

Comment: @roganjosh the question mark is for you to help me create the variable.

Comment: `Y = ` _does_ create a variable. You've not said anything about what that variable should be. A list? A Series? A numpy array?

Comment: @roganjosh Apologies for not specifying earlier, it should be a NumPy Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable from a Pandas column like this:

```py
Y = df['tipAmount'].values
```

Now, you have a NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable by grabbing the specific location:

```
df.loc[1]['tipAmount']
# 17
```

of getting all the data like:

```
y = df.tipAmount.tolist()
# [ 5,17,11,8,14,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point. After creating the dataframe you can use:

```
Y = data['tipAmount']
```

Now you are going to have a pandas Series.

type (Y) could help you to confirm the data type

```
0            5            
1           17           
2           11            
3            8            
4           14            
5            5
```